# Make a new anchor live in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new anchor via the code below. The addButton function works perfectly and adds the appropriate element in the appropriate spot.

However, that element is not "active". Specifically, I can't click it like I can the others.

Why is this the case? I thought because I added through a $(document).on("click"...) it gets added automatically to the DOM? (The pointer even changes icon's to indicate a button!)

```
$(document).on("click", "#addFavorite-button", function(){addButton();});


function addButton(){
    var uid = $("#main_container").attr("uid");
    var ticker = $("#main_container").attr("ticker");
    var exchange = $("#main_container").attr("exchange");

    var mydiv = document.getElementById("buttonlist");
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('class',"button widget d-margins stockButton");
    aTag.setAttribute('uid',uid);
    aTag.setAttribute('exchange',exchange);
    aTag.setAttribute('ticker',ticker);
    aTag.setAttribute('data-uib',"app_framework/button");   
    aTag.setAttribute('data-ver',"0");
    aTag.setAttribute('id',ticker+"-"+exchange+"-button");
    aTag.innerHTML = ticker;
    mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
};
```

**Edit:**
Too large to add to a fiddle but I uploaded a working version [here:](http://www.alrig.com/test)

To see it work, type in "FB", click go. Then hit settings "add stock to favorites" and "done. Then click the "favorites" button. You will see the FB option. However, if you click any other stock, like MSFT, you can't click and get back to FB again. The text in the middle doesn't change back.

Comment: can you put all the related contents in a fiddle and share the link? we can't see what framework you're using!

Comment: Too long to put in a fiddle but I provided a working example on my site directly. I'm using the intel app framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **index_user_scripts.js** file replace the following script lines :

**Replace**

```
$(".stockButton").click(function(evt){
     uib_sb.toggle_sidebar($("#leftPanel")); 
     setView($(this).attr("uid"),$(this).attr("ticker"), $(this).attr("exchange"));
});
```

(**Update**)
**With**

```
$('#buttonlist').on('click','.stockButton',function(evt){
   uib_sb.toggle_sidebar($("#leftPanel")); 
   setView($(this).attr("uid"),$(this).attr("ticker"), $(this).attr("exchange"));
});
```

**Explanation**

The former script delegates an event to all the elements having selector **'.stockButton'** which are currently in DOM. it doesn't work for dynamically added elements.

The Later script supports delegating events to dynamically added child elements. it is ***NOT always recommended*** to delegate events through '**document**'.

Preferably you should *delegate the event through the closest parent of the child element*.

As you can see the script mentioned in answer by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)

```
$('#buttonlist').on('click', '.stockButton', function(event) {
    // your click handler here
});
```

in the script above **#buttonlist** is the closest parent of all the child button (favorite buttons)

Here's the reference to **[.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** in case you may want to look at.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Would you mind writing a brief explanation on the difference? Why did $(document) need to be selected first? I'm learning by trial & error a bit and this would be super helpful. Thank you again :-).

Comment: @RobG: sure, please have a look at updated answer, thanks for pointing on that!

Comment: @Sunny, so do I still need $(document).on("click", "#addFavorite-button", function(){addButton();});? Can I just add that via a .click event?  -- tested- yes I can.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using jQuery, so you might as well make it work for you:

```
$('<a>', {
    "class": "button widget d-margins stockButton",
    "id": ticket + "-" + exchange + "-button",
    "href": "#", // you will need this in some browsers
    "uid": uid, // invalid attribute
    "exchange": exchange, // invalid attribute
    "ticket": ticket // invalid attribute
})
    .data({
        "uib": "app_framework/button",
        "ver": 0
    });
    .appendTo('#buttonlist');
```

To make this work you additionally need to set up a [delegated click handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on `#buttonlist` which is the closest DOM element that will likely not be removed:

```
$('#buttonlist').on('click', '.stockButton', function(event) {
    // your click handler here
});
```

And remove your existing `$('stockButton').click(...)`.

I've also added the `href` attribute; some browsers don't like anchors without it.

Please note that `uid`, `exchange` and `ticket` aren't valid attributes for an element, so I would suggest to use `.data()` for them as well.

Comment: This works too. Why use $('buttonlist').on('click','.stockButton'...) rather than on $(document).on('click', '.stockButton'...)

Comment: @user1357015 It's not recommended to use `document` because jQuery code will be called on all clicks on the page, but you really only want to have the code run when a button inside `#buttonlist` is clicked.

Comment: Thanks! also, any reason to use the jquery instead of the javascript that I did? I thought writing pure javascript was a bit faster?

Comment: @user1357015 The simplicity of element creation using jQuery outweighs the slight speed improvement you would get when using native JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, so to make sure I read the code right: $('#buttonlist').on('click', '.stockButton', function(event) {
    // your click handler here
}); means that for every created child of div buttonList with class stockButton, the click handler is automatically created. That means the "addFavorite-button" does not need to be .on(click... as i'm never adding subelements too it. That element can be called on a regular .click?

Comment: @user1357015 Yeah, you're probably correct to say that :)